# Making an algorithm more readable using LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make my algorithm more readable in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Detecta \textit{Slowloris}}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \Function{Divide\_slices\_1min }{Arquivo PCAP}
        \State \Return \textit{sliceAtual}
        \EndFunction
        \Function{Separa\_IP\_Origem\_Destino}{sliceAtual}
        \State \Return $ArquivoIPs$
        \EndFunction
        \Function{Calcula\_entropia\_IP\_Origem\_Destino}{ArquivoIP}
        \State \Return $EntroSliceAtualIP$
        \EndFunction
        \Function{PVS}{sliceAtual}
        \State \Return $PVS_SliceAtual$
        \EndFunction

        \Function{FCS}{sliceAtual}
        \State \Return $FCS_SliceAtual$
        \EndFunction

        \If {$entropiaSliceAtual$ > $entropiaSemAtaq$ + 0,10*$entropiaSemAtaq$}
        \If {$PVS_SliceAtual$ > $PVS_SemAtaq$ + 0.60*$PVS_SemAtaq$}  
        \If {$FCS_SliceAtual$ > $FCS_SemAtaq$ - 0.40*$FCS_SemAtaq$}

        \State \Return $Ataque$
        \Else
        \State \Return $SemAtaques$
        \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \EndIf

    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The result was not so good:

[image]

I would like it to appear just the call to the functions without the lot of endif.

I would like something like this:

[image: I would like something like this]

Any suggestion? I am trying hard!
The classe IEEEtran is : https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en

Comment: So you just want to remove the 3 **end if**s? You're also using math mode incorrectly.

Comment: yes: all "ends" -> end if , end function. Could you help me?

Comment: @Werner: Is it my algorithm clear?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example ? (with the list of `\usepackage` you use, etc...), because it is hard to guess what you use.

Comment: @Bromind: Thanks! I have edited the question!

Comment: Yep, that's better. However, what I meant was the list of `\usepackage` you use in your minimal working example. A good way to do that is to consider the problem you have (here removing the `end ...` in the produced document), and to remove all what is not necessary, so that readers can copy/paste the ~20 remaining lines. Said otherwise, readers want to copy/paste/compile some source which are required to produce your problem (and only it, for instance here, I don't think natbib is required) :-)

Comment: @Bromind: I edited with an usefull code!

Answer (score 10):

> — So you just want to remove the 3 `end if`s?
>   — Yes, all "ends": `end if` , `end function`.

If so, you just need to replace

```latex
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

with

```latex
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

---

Sources:

- paragraph 3.1.9 in [algorithmics.pdf](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)
- lines 66–74 in [algpseudocode.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty)

Comment: I have replaced it but it did not make any change on my end